# Updating Parquet Partition files with new values/rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet

For this example say I have a dataframe of 5000 rows and 5 columns. I have used the following line to create a parquet file partitioned on 'partition_key' (I have ~30 unique PKs):

```
dataframe.to_parquet(filename,engine='pyarrow',compression='snappy', partition_cols = 
'partition_key')
```

I am reading the parquet file into my jupyter notebook and a subset dataframe using the filters parameter (say result is 100 rows, 5 cols) successfully via:

```
new_df = pd.read_parquet(filename, engine = 'pyarrow', filters = one of the partition keys)
```

What I need to do is update values in the 'new_df' dataframe and then save it back, and/or replace the exact 100 entries/rows in the original parquet file. Is there way to either update the original parquet file, or perhaps delete the partition folder that I grabbed via the filter parameter and do my edits to the 'new_df' and append to the original parquet file?

Any suggestions are appreciated!